# JavaScript only works in <script> tags, but not in js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble with my JavaScript file.  Specifically for my Modal Slides and Individual Image Modal sections, I can get them to work when I add them as a  tag in the HTML, but they do not work when I add them in the js file. Basically, I am trying to create this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp, but without the pictures on the bottom.  I feel like I'm halfway there, but didn't adjust everything correctly.

I've tried searching on Stack Overflow for an answer, but was unable to find one, so I apologize if this is a duplicate.  Any help is much appreciated.

Here is the bottom of my HTML:

```
    <!-- ============================= -->
    <!-- All your JavaScript comes now -->
    <!-- ============================= -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JS -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Can place script tags with JavaScript files here -->
    <script src="js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>



  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Slideshow Speed
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 8000
    });

    //Smooth Scrolling
    var $root = $('html, body');
    $('.navbar-nav a').click(function() {
        var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
        $root.animate({
            scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
        }, 500, function () {
            window.location.hash = href;
        });
        return false;
    });

    //Collapse Navbar
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".navbar-nav li a").click(function(event) {
            $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
        });
    });

    // Stellar
    $(window).stellar();

    // Tooltips
    $(function () {
        $('#item1').tooltip();
    });
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });

    //Modal Slides
    function openModal() {
      document.getElementById('our-adventures-modal').style.display = "block";
    }
    function closeModal() {
      document.getElementById('our-adventures-modal').style.display = "none";
    }
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);
    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }
    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }
    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
      var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
      if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
          dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
      dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
      captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
    }

    //Individual Image Modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    var img = $('.myImg');
    var modalImg = $("#img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    $('.myImg').click(function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        var newSrc = this.src;
        modalImg.attr('src', newSrc);
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    });
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }

});
```

Comment: In your `js` file, add the following: `alert('hello');`. This will indicate whether it’s loading and running properly.

Comment: Try to find out whether the browser shows errors via pression F12 and switching to console. Perhaps the path is broken or something.

Comment: Yep.  Just tried that and the alert pops up.

Comment: This is what is shown in the console (doesn't appear to be related):

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined
    at showSlides (scripts.js:69)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (scripts.js:48)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: Check if  `dots[i]` is not undefined as well as `dots[slideIndex-1]` otherwise the error is thrown.

Comment: Where would I go to check that?  In the HTML file?  I am fairly new to JavaScript, so still learning my way around.

Comment: Also, unrelated, but you should remove extraneous jquery 'ready' calls, e.g.:

`    $(function () {
        $('#item1').tooltip();
    });
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
`
Basically, just as Stephen mentioned, it appears that dots[n] isn't the type you're expecting and doesn't have a className.

Comment: you can `console.log(dots[i]);` you can also set a breakpoint in devtools by clicking a line number and refreshing the page.

Comment: Can you try once using latest version of jquery.

Comment: How do I know what's considered a jquery 'ready' call?  I also tried console.log(dots[i]); and it looks like dots is not defined, but I'm not sure where to go to define it (or how).

Comment: You can define `dots` by having an element with `class="demo"` in the HTML.

Comment: Hold that thought.  I think I found where I need define dots.  Right now, it's pointing to a "demo" class that I'm pretty sure I updated the name.  Looking into it now.

Comment: Ok that fixed one error, but now two more came in it's place. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at showSlides (scripts.js:68)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (scripts.js:46)
    at j (jquery.js:3148)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3260)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:3472)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js:3503)
our-story.html:188 Uncaught ReferenceError: openModal is not defined
    at HTMLImageElement.onclick (our-story.html:188)

Comment: I actually just realized I added back the "demo" class to the wrong area in my HTML.  Where it needs to go was an area I didn't want to use, so I took it out.  I'm going to try and remove that part from the js file as well and see if that works.

Comment: That did not work.  Basically, I am trying to create this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp, but without the pictures on the bottom.  Any advise would be helpful as I think I am just making this worse.